# Configure clock signal for black box in Simulink/System Generator

Tags: simulink, fpga, zynq, system-generator

I use code VHDL to make a one-shot timer in Simulink by "black box" of System Generator. The module concludes input is: clk, en, trigger, delay & output is: pluse. Now I want to use System Generator to implement on Zynq 7020 and use clock frequency = 1.562Mhz. I read "ug897-vivado-system generator-user", but i still dont know how to configure clk.

**The diagram in Matlab/Simulink**

[image: enter image descriptioefern here]

**The VHDL code for one-shot timer/black box**

```
 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
 use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
 library UNISIM;
 use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

 entity oneshot is
     port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        ce : in STD_LOGIC;
        trigger : in STD_LOGIC:='0';
        delay : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
        pulse : out STD_LOGIC :='0');
 end oneshot;

 architecture Behavioral of oneshot is
     signal count: INTEGER range 0 to 255; -- count variable
     signal bus_rising_edge : boolean;
     signal input_sync : std_logic_vector(0 to 2);
 begin
      input_syncronizer : process(clk) begin
          if rising_edge(clk) then 
             input_sync <= to_x01(trigger)&input_sync(0 to 1);
          end if; 
      end process ;

bus_rising_edge <= input_sync(0 to 1) = "10";


trigger_process: process (clk)
begin
-- wait for trigger leading edge
if rising_edge(clk) then 
   if bus_rising_edge then
        pulse <= '1';   
        count <= to_integer(unsigned(delay));
   elsif count > 1 then  
        pulse <= '1';
        count <= count - 1;
    else
        pulse <= '0';
    end if;
end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

**The Matlab code automatically create when importing VHDL code**
   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jfztL-NgftDc7VAgAX4eHfuJF8uOgK3V

(sorry i cant post my code properly)

Answer (score 0):

You can double click on system generator mark and select the clocking tab and change the period of your clock. this clock is use for simulation. in real, your operation clock is one you have on your board.